# How to generate tracking number using fedex api?

Tags: php

How to generate tracking number using fedex api ?
when we can describe product details or other information in this api than after they can generate the tracking number using fedex api but how i get the api for this process.

Please any body know this process so tell me

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an account with FedEx and API keys:

http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/